# Update component position at run time

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, tablelayout, updating

I'm currently stuck with the following problem:

I need to dynamically update component positioning at run time. I'm making a form editor for an external application. I use wrapper-classes for standard Swing components, currently `JPanel` and `JLabel`. Panels are using **`TableLayout`**. I'm storing each component position in a field for each component. When something is changed, I need to recursively update all positions. Here is my method for updating positions:

```
 public void updatePositioning() {
    Component[] comps = getComponents();
    removeAll();
    for (Component comp:comps) {
        System.out.println("Moving component "+comp + " to x="+pos.get(comp).getX() 
                +" to y="+pos.get(comp).getY());   
        c = new TableLayoutConstraints(String.valueOf(pos.get(comp).getX())+","
                +String.valueOf(pos.get(comp).getY()));

        add(comp, c);
        if (comp instanceof EditPanel) ((EditPanel)comp).updatePositioning();
    }
    repaint();
    revalidate(); 
}
```

I know, it's rough, but it's not working. All the components are seems to belong to 0,0 grid cell. X's and Y's are correct, as I've seen through debugger. Here is how I add components to my panel:

```
public void addComponent(TableLayouted comp, int x, int y) {
    c = new TableLayoutConstraints(String.valueOf(x)+","+String.valueOf(y));
    add((JComponent) comp, c);
    //saving position of the component
    pos.put((Component) comp, comp.getTablePositon());
    System.out.println("Component "+comp+"added to x="+x+"y="+y);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doubt it will make a difference, but for future reference it should be revalidate() followed by repaint(). Order can be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

[JComponent.getTopLevelAncestor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor%28%29).[validate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29)

Comment: Excuse me, where should I insert this code. I've inserted it before my repaint(); revalidate();, and it doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: Into your source.  For a more specific answer, add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it with the following code:

```
Component[] comps = getComponents();
removeAll();
layout = new TableLayout();
layout.setColumn(columns);
layout.setRow(rows);
setLayout(layout);
```

Which means, fully re-creating all layouts is working. Thanks everyone for help!